# When locating elements with CSS Selector in Selenium, is it less efficient to use * over the tagname?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, ui-automation

Assuming I'm trying to find all elements with the "description" class, and knowing beforehand the class would only appear on `<p>` tags, which of these would run faster?

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*.description"))`

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.description"))`

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".description"))`

I would expect

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.description"))`

to be the fastest, however I am not sure as I could not find anything about this online.

Comment: Probably depend on the underlying implementation. I suspect running performance tests would be only mildly interesting.

Comment: Focus on clarity and specificity: `p.description` provides more usable information.

Comment: You could run performance tests to find out for sure but my guess is that the difference is on the order of a few ms which on a web test will easily be negligible.

Comment: The difference is quite small for sure, the idea of locators is to have a unique identification rather than fast. Anyway, any utility loads the whole html document into memory and proceeds with parsing by whatever criteria you provided. So, it depends on structure where it was loaded and CPU performance.

Comment: doesn't `p.description` hurt the test's stability? The element could theoretically become a span or an h1 tag, for example, while retaining the functionality. We'd still want the test to pass in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

`p.description` will be faster , reason for that when it start searching for match of cssSelector in dom it start by tag `<P>` first , get all the tag with `p`  then filter which has class `description`.

for case `*.description` it will list all element then search for `description` class in list

`.description` can be fastest depends on if only `<p>` has this class